# Apache Spark doesn't perform dynamic Allocation as expected

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have the following settings in my Spark that runs in AWS EMR cluster. Based on these settings, Spark should allocate up to 10 executors to my job. But I see only 2 executors allocated even when no other jobs are running. And I see lots of unused processor capacity. What can be the problem? How can I diagnose such problems?

```
spark.app.id    ABC
spark.app.name  XYZ
spark.app.startTime 1699623174356
spark.blacklist.decommissioning.enabled true
spark.blacklist.decommissioning.timeout 1h
spark.decommissioning.timeout.threshold 20
spark.default.parallelism   100
spark.driver.cores  4
spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.driver.extraClassPath ****
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   *********(redacted)
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath   *****
spark.driver.host   ****
spark.driver.memory 20g
spark.driver.port   41783
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst false
spark.dummy.for.ops 548510a92b094285a4d3568ada11c44a
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors    10
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors    2
spark.emr.default.executor.cores    4
spark.emr.default.executor.memory   18971M
spark.eventLog.dir  *****
spark.eventLog.enabled  true
spark.executor.cores    4
spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions   -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.executor.extraClassPath   /lib/spark/jars/*:/home/hadoop/extrajars/*:/var/log/log4j2-config.xml
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions *********(redacted)
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath *********
spark.executor.id   driver
spark.executor.memory   20g
spark.executor.memoryOverhead   1500
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst   false
spark.executorEnv.AAA_APPLICATION_NAME  DoomSpark
spark.executorEnv.AAA_AWS_CLIENT_RELATIONSHIP_KEY_BUCKET_NAME   aaastack-prod-na-syncbucketcfnbucketc68d5f32-1mafjvqn9i9gj
spark.executorEnv.CORAL_CONFIG_PATH /home/hadoop/.config/coral-config
spark.executorEnv.DOMAIN    prod
spark.executorEnv.ENVROOT   /home/hadoop
spark.executorEnv.REALM USAmazon
spark.executorEnv.REDIS_AUTH_TOKEN  *********(redacted)
spark.executorEnv.REDIS_PORT    6379
spark.executorEnv.REDIS_URL master.rediscfnreplicationgroup-prod-na.f12qkp.use1.cache.amazonaws.com
spark.files.fetchFailure.unRegisterOutputOnHost true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.getObject.initialSocketTimeoutMilliseconds   2000
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem    2
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup-failures.ignored.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem true
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.output.fs.optimized.committer.enabled    true
spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled  false
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.ui.port   18080
spark.master    yarn
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_HOSTS  ip-10-0-52-16.ec2.internal
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_URI_BASES  http://ip-10-0-52-16.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1699353854257_0781
spark.resourceManager.cleanupExpiredHost    true
spark.scheduler.mode    FAIR
spark.serializer    org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.shuffle.service.enabled   true
spark.sql.emr.internal.extensions   com.amazonaws.emr.spark.EmrSparkSessionExtensions
spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2
spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled   true
spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class    com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
spark.sql.warehouse.dir hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse
spark.stage.attempt.ignoreOnDecommissionFetchFailure    true
spark.submit.deployMode cluster
spark.submit.pyFiles    
spark.ui.filters    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
spark.ui.port   0
spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir    /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1699353854257_0781/container_1699353854257_0781_01_000001
spark.yarn.app.id   application_1699353854257_0781
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DOMAIN  prod
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.REALM   USAmazon
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS    $(hostname -f)
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverheadFactor    0.1875
spark.yarn.heterogeneousExecutors.enabled   false
spark.yarn.historyServer.address    ip-XXXXX.internal:XXXX
spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion false
spark.yarn.tags livy-batch-780-2iPUo7av
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have dynamic allocation enabled in the spark config,

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors    10
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors    2
```

It is because of dynamic allocation your application is scaled down to the number of minExecutors you have set in spark config.

In case when more resources will be required spark will spawn more executors & will scale down when not needed.

For more info please refer - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation